# Wait for List of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

How to wait for list of futures for 15 minutes( if not completed)  and not each future?
Below code will wait for each future for 15 minutes.But thats's not what i want

```
for (CompleteableFuture<String> m : futureList) {
        m.get(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES) ;
}

Syso( " Send email") ;
```

Comment: Maybe you could keep track of how much time passed and only wait for the remaining time in subsequent iterations?

Comment: If switching to Guava is an option to you then you could use `com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures#allAsList(ListenableFuture...)`

Comment: Yes actually i am getting 
List<ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>>> myKafkaFutures

But allAsList doesn't have option of passing Time

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CompletableFuture.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) like so:

```
       CompletableFuture.allOf(futureList).get(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Note that `allOf()` takes an array. If `futureList` is a `List` or `Collection` it'll need to be converted.